# Is the phrase "blind someone with science" understood or used in America?

Tags: british-english, north-american-english

This definition states (with my added emphasis),

> **blind with science**  (**British & Australian**)
> If you blind someone with science, you confuse them by
> using technical language that they are not likely to understand.
>
> *I think he decided to blind us with science because he didn't want us
> asking any difficult questions.*
>
> [theFreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blind+with+science)

This expression is so common in Britain, where I live, I was surprised it is defined as being limited to certain areas.

Is this phrase really so unfamiliar to, say, U. S. English speakers?

Comment: ["She Blinded Me With Science"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMWGXt979yg) is the first thing I thought of upon reading this question. It's not a phrase I use in everyday speech (Californian English speaker)

Comment: I think this is true. I know the expression only from the Thomas Dolby song.

Comment: Interesting. I had never heard of the song. I looked it up and the singer is British!

Comment: Yes. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She_Blinded_Me_with_Science) says it was relatively more popular in the US than in the UK, for some reason. It seems quite likely that Dolby knew of the UK idiom.

Comment: I've heard it (the phrase, not the song), but I would not call it "familiar", and I would not necessarily apply that specific meaning.

Comment: @HotLicks, I see. What other meaning might it have? To me it simply means to talk a lot of technical (or technical-sounding) jargon, usually to win an argument with someone who doesn't know the technical terms or maybe just doesn't have a very extensive vocabulary.  E,g, "*Don't try to blind me with science--I know more about this than you do and I'll call your bluff!*"

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - To me it more implies (out of any context) an individual who uses pseudo-science to refute a scientific argument.  But like I said, it's not really familiar to me.

Comment: The other possible meaning I had was that the possibilities offered by science "blinded" someone to the moral questions relative to the subject.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I know it from the song but never use it in speech.  In the UK, I think this is a good answer for the post that your question is related to...but elsewhere...

Comment: Never heard of the song, "She blinded me with science"?! Now you'll be telling me that you've never heard of the Buggles, "Video killed the radio star" or Manfred Mann's "[Blinded by the light](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcWVL4B-4pI)" I guess, I must be showing my age. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression appears to be mainly a British one; according to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blind%20with%20science&year_start=1930&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblind%20with%20science%3B%2Cc0) the only evidence of its usage is in BrE. Its origin  predates the 1982  [song](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/She_Blinded_Me_with_Science) which probably made the expression more popular. Here is an earlier example from 1947:

From: *Failure of the Left, A Plea for a New Liberalism*  (1947)

> - ... he is dreaming in terms of classes and class exploitation : ***his references to the mundane world are merely there to blind with science the proselyte who will not take his religion without evidence of a sort.*** When one contemplates the actual ...

According to [The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](https://books.google.it/books?id=Ak6cBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1409&dq=%22blind%20with%20science%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMItsrp7IDeyAIVAn0aCh2bcglK#v=onepage&q=%22blind%20with%20science%22&f=false) the expression "blind with science" first appeared in 1937 in Australia and in 1943 in UK.

Answer (score 2):

While I have only ever heard it used in the above mentioned song I have been familiar with the phrase my whole life. A similar phrase that I have heard used is to "baffle'em with bullshit" which is an abbreviated version of

> “If you can't dazzle them with brilliance, baffle them with bullshit.”
>   ― W.C. Fields

Answer (score 1):

Cary Grant as Ernie Mott quotes the phrase in 1944' "None but the Lonely Heart", the film based upon the 1943 novel of the same name.