# Word for "Trying to confuse people with Scientific and technical jargon"

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a word for the following expression:

---

To confuse people by using Scientific/ Technical/ obscure words (may be in an attempt to prove something or convince them of something.)

---

This word was on my vocabulary a long time ago. I haven't been able to remember it for a while now. I am pretty sure it's a single word.

For some reason if you think this might be a phrasal verb please feel free to include them in your suggestions.

P.S. Words like *bombastic, pompous, grandiloquent etc* are not the one's I'm looking for and clearly these doesn't properly match the meaning. Other than these, if you can stretch the definition a tad bit and point a word, it's fine.

Comment: Related [To Blind Someone With Science](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282538/to-blind-someone-with-science-not-known-or-rare-in-the-us/282571#282571)

Comment: Well, if you are looking for a negative meaning (e.g. Someone who just tries to impress people with jargon that he doesn't even understand very well himself), there's a saying: "if you can't dazzle people with brilliance, **baffle** 'em with bullshit."

Comment: Not quite the meaning you describe, but there's "gobbledygook".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Words with usage similar to what you've described:

- Obfuscate
- Bamboozle
- Bewilder

I'd say obfuscate is closest. It's the one that particularly implies that you're trying to fool someone with complicated words or details.

This previous question has additional answers:

[What is deliberately using complex sentences to confuse people called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254643/what-is-deliberately-using-complex-sentences-to-confuse-people-called)

Aside from obfuscate, these other two answers seem most likely to be the word you've been thinking of:

- Convolute (this is most commonly used as the adjective convoluted alongside a simpler verb like 'used'; e.g. "They used convoluted speech to hide the truth of the situation.")
- Circumlocute (this is most commonly used in its noun form, as circumlocution; e.g. "His writing was full of circumlocution.")

Comment: I think obfuscate comes pretty close and it'll probably work in most contexts with some explanation. But I am aware of these three words and will wait out to see if someone comes with a more specialized suggestion. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

technobabble

Technobabble (a portmanteau of technology and babble), also called technospeak, is a form of jargon that consists of buzzwords, esoteric language, specialized technical terms, or technical slang that is impossible to understand for the listener.

Verb would be I guess technobabbling

---

sesquipedaliate

sesquipedalian speech or writing is characterised by the overuse of long words

A recent coining by the Sesquipedalian Society is the verb sesquipedaliate.

---

abstrusity. 1 : the quality or state of being abstruse

But I guess there’s no verb form so we’d have to coin the term abstrusify.

---

This is relatively new term:

geekify

Make something geeky.

Geekified. New Word Suggestion. a person or persons that has a unique talent in a specific subject.